# Getting KeyError 2 even after making all the three files in required format for BERT

Tags: python, tensorflow, compiler-errors

I made all the three files in the required format. I am getting an error on executing run_classifier.py. I have attached the picture for reference

Also, It is generating an error after processing a bit of data. What am I doing wrong?

The output:

[image: my output screenshot]

Comment: `label_map` does not have key 2

Comment: What task are you using as task_name? I have only ever seen MRPC and CoLA used. Both these tasks are classification tasks with two classes 0 and 1. So you should never have that example.label is equal to 2.

Comment: I have encountered similar problem, but ain't sure if its the same. Can you please tell me, how many classes do you have?